# DevExpress WebForms - limit number of rows to export

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have DevEx webform application that I am working on. I'd like to hook into the export functionality and show an error message if the number of rows in the grid are greater than say 10,000 and to not allow users to export more than 10,000 records at a time. How do I do that?

I have a ViewController and I am hooking into ExportController's CustomExport event but not sure where to go from there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten "You can only export 10,000 records at a time". i.e. we show an error message to the user that they are not allowed to export more than 10,000 records. So I need to see how many records they have, if it's less continue with the export, if it's more show the message that they are not allowed to in a popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Grid exports as many records as it has matched a current filter. So, you can use the [ASPxGridView.VisibleRowCount](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_VisibleRowCounttopic) property to get the current row number in the Grid and based on it, display your warning to a user.